# Creating an enum from its name not value

Tags: enums, raku

Given the enumeration

```
enum NATO (:alpha<A>, :bravo<B>, :charlie<C>, :delta<D>);
```

it's possible to easily set a variable by literally typing one of the names, or by passing one of the values to the enum object:

```
my $a = alpha;
my $b = NATO('B');

say $a;        # ↪︎ alpha
say $b;        # ↪︎ bravo
say $a.value;  # ↪︎ A
say $b.value;  # ↪︎ B
```

Besides using `EVAL` and given a `Str` that corresponds to one of the enums, how could I create `$c` to be an enum value equivalent to `charlie`?

```
my $x = 'charlie';
my $c =  ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use indirect name lookup:

```
enum NATO (:alpha<A>, :bravo<B>, :charlie<C>);
my $x = 'charlie';
my $c = ::($x);
say $c.value;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can treat it as a Hash:

```
my $c = NATO::{$x};
```

Comment: Ah, I needed the double colon. I definitely had tried just using the `NATO{$x}` to no avail. Thanks for a great alternate answer (it's longer than @ugexe 's, but for situations where `::($x)` won't make it obvious what's going on, `Foo::{$x}` will make it crystal clear.

Comment: @guifa the trailing `::` gives you the symbol table, where all the enum items reside. That's why `NATO::{...}` work.