# How to convert Str to enum?

Tags: enums, type-conversion, raku

```
enum Colors<red green blue>

say red;  # OUTPUT: red

my $foo = "red";

my Colors $color = $foo.(...)
```

What code do I put in the Stub to convert the Str "red" to the Color red?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an enum from its name not value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55769656/creating-an-enum-from-its-name-not-value)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `enum` declarator installs the elements under the `Colors` package as well as providing the short names, thus `red` can also be accessed as `Colors::red`. Therefore, one can use the package lookup syntax to do the job:

```
my Colors $color = Colors::{$foo};
```

Optionally providing an error or default:

```
my Colors $color = Colors::{$foo} // die "No such color $foo";
```